# Prove that E$(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} X_n )\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}E(X_n)$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I want to prove that if $X_n\geq 0$, then 
E$(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n )\leq \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}E(X_n)$.

My attempt:

$E(\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n)=E(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \min\limits_{k\geq n} X_k)$. Since $\min\limits_{k\geq n} E(X_k)$ is non-decreasing, I can exchange limit and $E$.
So:

$E(\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n)=E(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \min\limits_{k\geq n} X_k)=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(\min\limits_{k\geq n} X_k)$.

Also, since $\min\limits_{k\geq n} X_k \leq X_n$, from the monotonicity of the operator $E$, I get $E(\min\limits_{k\geq n} X_k) \leq E(X_n)$. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Look up a proof of "Fatou's lemma."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma

Comment: The proof in the book A probability path by Sidney Resnick goes like this:

$E(\liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}X_n)=E(\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\bigwedge\limits_{k=n}^\infty X_k))$

$=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(\bigwedge\limits_{k=n}^\infty X_k) $

$\leq \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} E(X_n)$. 

I do not understand the last step.